# Get value from json in LogicApp

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, jsonpath

Rephrasing question entirely, as first attempt was unclear.

In my logic app I am reading a .json from blob which contains:

```
{
    "alpha": {
        "url": "https://linktoalpha.com",
        "meta": "This logic app does job aaaa"
    },
    "beta": {
        "url": "https://linktobeta.com",
        "meta": "This logic app does job beta"
    },
    "theta": {
        "url": "https://linktotheta.com",
        "meta": "This logic app does job theta"
    }
}
```

I'm triggering the logic app with a http post which contains in the body:

```
{ "logicappname": "beta" }
```

But the value for 'logicappname' could be alpha, beta or theta. I now need to set a variable which contains the url value for 'beta'. How can this be achieved without jsonpath support?

I am already json parsing the file contents from the blob and this IS giving me the tokens... but I cannot see how to select the value I need. Would appreciate any assistance, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your requirement, I think just use "Parse JSON" action to do it. Please refer to the steps below:

**1.** I upload a file `testJson.json` to my blob storage, then get it and parse it in my logic app.
[image]

**2.** We can see there are three `url` in the screenshot below. As you want to get the `url` value for `beta`, it is the second one, so we can choose the second one.
[image]

If you want to get the `url` value by the param `logicappname` from the "When a HTTP request is received" trigger, you can use a expression when you create the `result` variable.
[image]

In my screenshot, the expression is:

```
body('Parse_JSON')?[triggerBody()?['logicappname']]?['url']
```

As the description of your question is a little unclear and I'm confused about the meaning of `I am already json parsing the file contents from the blob and this IS giving me the tokens`, why is "tokens" involved in it ? And in the original question it seems you want to do it by jsonpath but in the latest description you said `without jsonpath` ? So if I misunderstand your question, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response!
Yes, this worked :-) Fantastic.

I can see that the expression you made is effectively achieving what jsonpath would do. i.e. Selection of the property using the dynamic value to ensure the correct/required value is returned. 

Initially, I wanted to know if there was a way to "do" jsonpath in logic apps. It appears there is no direct support for jsonpath. Once I realised that traditional jsonpath was not an option I switched around to try to ask "what is correct logic app way to do this". Your answer addresses this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question. But I believe you can use Pars Json action after the http trigger.
With this you will get a control over the incoming JSON message and you can choose the 'URL' value as a dynamic content in the subsequent actions.
Let me know if my understanding about your question is wrong.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am aware of the json parse, but not clear on how that helps me to make a focussed selection of the value I need. I have simplified and re-written the question. Are you able to advise on how json parse could be used to achieve this?